# Has Peter ever shared his secret web formula with the other Spiders?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man

I'd assume that [Spider-Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Girl_(Mayday_Parker)) (or sometimes also called as Spider-Woman and is *the daughter of Peter and MJ Parker*) may have received the formula from her dad.

However, speaking of the other spiders (Miles Morales, Gwen Stacy etc.), did Peter share his secret formula with anyone else? This could be either [temporarily] to face crisis, or [permanently] to help a fellow Spider.